# vue-test-utils - how to handle $refs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

**THE SITUATION**

I am trying to `shallowMount` a component, unsuccessfully.

The component makes use of `$refs` to read the height of a `div`. That value is read inside a computed property. Then in the `mounted` lifecycle I save that value in the store.

The logic itself is simple and works fine. But **in the test suite, the mounting of the component breaks, because the `$refs` key is `undefined`.**

To be clear: I don't intend to test the `$refs`, I just need to mount the component and move on doing actual unit-testing.

**THE COMPONENT**

This is the markup:

```
<div ref="tgmp">
```

I save the height of the div in a computed property:

```
computed: {
  barH() {
    return this.$refs.tgmp.clientHeight
  }
}
```

And then, in the mounted lifecycle, I commit the value in the store:

```
this.$store.commit('setBarHeight', this.barH)
```

**THE TEST**

This is the test. I have omitted irrelevant stuff, like installing the store in the localVue.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallowMount(Bar, {
    store,
  })
})

test('is a Vue instance', () => {
  expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
})
```

**THE ERROR**

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of undefined"
```

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of undefined]

**ATTEMPT**

I have been trying searching anywhere for a solution, but couldn't find it.
I have tried to mock the $refs, but without success:

```
wrapper = shallowMount(ThePlayerBar, {
  store,
  mocks: {
    $refs: {
      tgmp: {
        clientHeight: 600
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**THE QUESTION**

How can I mount a component that makes us of `$refs` in the `mounted` lifecycle?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with refs in shallowMount, but you can try `mount` with specific stubs or mock a computed.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for replying! It seems it's working. I will make some more stuff to be sure of it. If you want you can reply since it seems the correct solution.

Comment: I checked it and I'd expect a ref to be there in your case. Probably `<div ref="tgmp">` doesn't exist when you render it, could be if it's a child of other component or affected by a directive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`shallowMount` is supposed to provide refs, so `this.$refs.tgmp` should be `<div>` element in case `<div ref="tgmp">` exists in the view on initial render.

`$refs` isn't supposed to be mocked because it's internal property and assigned on component initialization. It's computed property that relies on a ref, so it can be mocked if necessary because element height is expected to be 0 in JSDOM:

```
jest.spyOn(ThePlayerBar.options.computed, 'barH').mockReturnValue(600);
```

Or:

```
  wrapper = shallowMount(Bar, {
    store,
    computed: { barH: () => 600 }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That spy doesn't seem to work. I get errors like: Cannot read property 'computed' of undefined. Property barH does not have access type get. But I managed to make it working by stubbing the computed property as you suggested in the comment: `computed: { barH() { return 60 }}`
That spyOn did you tested in this condition? In case you can edit the answer or I can add that computed stub as an edit to my question.

Comment: I updated the answer with both ways. I'm not sure under which condition a spy could fail because components have `options` exposed and it worked for me before, but I fixed it to be `jest.spyOn` with no `get`.